# Connecting android device with a handsfree car radio via bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

my question is connected with android device and being able to communicate with another device via bluetooth.

On one hand I have an android device with android 2.3.7 and on the other hand I have a PIONEER DEH-6400BT. I can successfully connect the two devices and do everything that is explained when using radio handsfree bluetooth communication.

The thing I am trying to do is the following:
I would like to connect to the radio via bluetooth(using bluetooth socket) and to be able to do anything with the radio that is connected with the radio's abilities to list contacts/add contact/show that a contact is dialing/or just showing some kind of string on the radio display.

In order to achieve this I started with the BluetoothChat example plus using the [InsecureBluetooth class](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CE8QFjAB&url=http://stanford.edu/~tpurtell/InsecureBluetooth.java&ei=jQXWT8CeFND0sgaY3rGYDw&usg=AFQjCNH-tOSqaNp4Hy5y_B683iWNP7r9Pw&sig2=tlVh5Y7sA5bLIgOqIzctlg) and at the beginning I started connecting with an ordinary bluetooth handsfree device. Surprisingly I achieved connecting with the device over Bluetoothsocket and I received the first message that starts the whole communication protocol (AT+BRSF:27) after which all communication broke and I did not receive any answer after sending anything. So this gives me some hope that I can connect with a device but I do  not know how to continue.

This is the most relevant code:

```
/**
 * This thread runs while listening for incoming connections. It behaves
 * like a server-side client. It runs until a connection is accepted
 * (or until cancelled).
 */
private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    // The local server socket
    private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

    public AcceptThread() {
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

        // Create a new listening server socket
        try {
            tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "listen() failed", e);
        }
        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);
        setName("AcceptThread");
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;

        // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
        while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
                Log.i(TAG, ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> SOCKEET accept() <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "accept() failed", e);
                break;
            }

            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {
                synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
                    switch (mState) {
                    case STATE_LISTEN:
                    case STATE_CONNECTING:
                        // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                        connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice());
                        break;
                    case STATE_NONE:
                    case STATE_CONNECTED:
                        // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate new socket.
                        try {
                            socket.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (D) Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread");
    }

    public void cancel() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "cancel " + this);
        try {
            mmServerSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of server failed", e);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection
 * with a device. It runs straight through; the connection either
 * succeeds or fails.
 */
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

        // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
        // given BluetoothDevice


        try {

//              tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
                tmp = InsecureBluetooth.createRfcommSocket(mmDevice, 10, false);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "create() failed", e);
            }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread");
        setName("ConnectThread");

        // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
        mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
        try {
            // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
            // successful connection or an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            connectionFailed();
            // Close the socket
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() socket during connection failure", e2);
            }
            // Start the service over to restart listening mode
            BluetoothChatService.this.start();
            return;
        }

        // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
        synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Start the connected thread
        connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
    }
```

You can notice that a line is commented out (tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);), which is the regular way of creating a BluetoothSocket but that way I could not connect even with the regular handsfree device. I have also tried using the reflection-way but that did not work either.

I have also tried any combination of paired/unpaired connected/disconnected status with no luck.

I crave for any tips.